# Show that there exist 1999 consecutive numbers, each of which is divisible by the cube of an integer

Tags: number-theory

Show that there exist $1999$ consecutive numbers, each of which is divisible by the cube of an integer.

I thought I had to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but each cube are not necessarily relatively prime. Is anyone is able to give me a hint? 
Can I use the fact that if $gcd (a, b) = d$, then $ gcd (\frac{a}{d}, \frac{b}{d}) = 1$ (with the Chinese Remainder Theorem)?  Please, I ask you to don't give me the answer; I would like to solve the problem myself.

Comment: The sequence of consecutive numbers, each divisible by a cube, can be arbitary long, since there are infinite many primes, and therefore arbitary many coprime cubes. The chinese remainder theorem is the right tool to prove this.

Comment: All integers are divisible by 1 = 1^3.  Consider (m + i)^3 = m^ + 3im^2 + 3i^2m + i^3.  What do  3im^2 + 3i^2m + i^3 span?  Maybe... just a thought.

Comment: @fleablood you are right, but I think, the OP looks for a non-trivial cube dividing each of the numbers.

Comment: *I would like to solve the problem myself* - Well, if you do, by all means, let us know, and post a solution. I'm really curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint : Use the cubes of the first $1,999$ primes. They are clearly pairwise coprime.